# Check checkbox with Espresso

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-espresso

I have a problem with checking the checkbox using Espresso library. My checkbox contains hyperlink (clickable text which opens web brower). When i use `onView(withId(R.id.termsAndCondition)).perform(click())` it just opens web brower.

Is there any possibility to check this chechkbox without changing program code? Checkbox hyperlink must be clickable

Comment: If you are running UI Automator Viewer, can you see is the checkbox clickable = True? You can open UI Automator Viewer like this: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing#inspecting-ui

Comment: Antoher optioncould be: ``onView(withId(R.id.termsAndCondition)).check(matches(isClickable()));``

Comment: Yes, my checkbox is clickable. The problem is that on click it opens web browser so the question is if is there any way to check it without clicking on it?

Comment: You can be sure that this Id exits, could be helpful. But this SO-answer could help, if you stub it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35067831/5132305

Comment: Thats not point of my question. In my app i have something like this:
`[ ] string`. Where `[ ]` is a checkbox and `string` is an hyperlink. When i manually click on `[ ]` it is checking the checkbox, and when i click `string` it opens the web browser. 

In my espresso tests i want to check my checkbox (like i would click on `[ ]`), but when im using `onView(withId(R.id.termsAndCondition)).perform(click())` it actually opens the web browser (like i would click on `string`).

Comment: Any solution found ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a good solution for that by clicking at the position 0, 0 of the checkbox

```
onView(withId(R.id.view)).check(matches(isNotChecked())).perform(clickPercent(0F, 0F));
```

and the clickPercent function

```
public static ViewAction clickPercent(final float pctX, final float pctY) {
    return new GeneralClickAction(
            Tap.SINGLE,
            view -> {
                final int[] screenPos = new int[2];
                view.getLocationOnScreen(screenPos);
                int w = view.getWidth();
                int h = view.getHeight();

                float x = w * pctX;
                float y = h * pctY;

                final float screenX = screenPos[0] + x;
                final float screenY = screenPos[1] + y;
                float[] coordinates = {screenX, screenY};

                return coordinates;
            },
            Press.FINGER,
            InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE,
            MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY);
}
```